# Can we take Sp website backup 2 times in a day?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Our Public facing website has developed on sharepoint 2013,

Daily automatic backup happens at 4am,
but when I try to copy that backup folder in other servers it's throwing an error that **Unspecified error**, and it's not copying anything.

Thus the reason I want to take backup manually today at 11pm using Central Administration.

So if I take backup in 2 times that too 4,5 hours later after taking first backup will it cause any performance issue??

Please if anyone has idea about it then kindly tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , Taking a backup of SharePoint site collection or site sets the site into read only mode till the backup process is done. so during business hours it needs to be avoided .

and there is no issue with the no of times the backup is being taken.